Harvester Ubuntu VM does not connect to network
I am trying to provision a Kubernetes cluster using Rancher and Harvester.
For testing purposes, I started manually creating a VM (I know that Rancher does that automatically when using Harvester as a cloud provider, but it's for testing and does not seem to work either).
Here is the overall setup:

Physical:

6 servers with some older server hardware (2016), 64 Cores, 1TB RAM
Connected via 2 physical NICs with a 1Gbit switch each (for separating management and cluster traffic).
Both switches are connected to the same firewall/DHCP server on different interfaces / networks.


Harvester Network layer:

Management network configured with physical NIC 1.
Cluster network "Intranet" configured with physical NIC 2.
VM network "k8s-net" on Intranet as UntaggedNetwork. (Also tried L2VlanNetwork)


VM

4 CPU, 8 GB RAM
Image: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/jammy/release/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img (also tried minimal-cloudimg)
Network: k8s-net, Model virtio, Type bridge
Advanced Options > Network (Netplan):
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens0:
      dhcp4: true
    ens1:
      dhcp4: true





The VM boots fine, but is unable to retrieve an IP address from the DHCP server.
ip a shows the interface is down:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 26:e8:9e:4e:bf:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Interestingly, virtio kernel modules are disabled, though I am not sure if this is a red herring.
ubuntu@test-1231:~$ lsmod | grep virt
ubuntu@test-1231:~$ 

When using e1000 as the NIC Model, everything appears to work!
This is not a solution in Rancher though, as it cannot be configured in the UI at least.
Overall I am running out of options to try. This issue has been bugging us and preventing the K8s setup for a while.

I turns out virtio was a red herring.
The actual issue was in the netplan config:
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp1s0: # this matches the name of the interface in the VM
      dhcp4: true

Although it is a little hard to predict which name the interfaces will have.
Probably netplan's match would help here
